Are the named character deaths in Into the Woods supposed to be symbolic or allegorical to anything?
The 2014 musical feature film Into the Woods contains multiple deaths of named characters who are dispatched both on and off screen in various ways that often seemed incidental to the main story, rather than a clear part of it, or ignominious to them as a character.
For example, Jack's Mother is struck on the head by the Steward with no foreshadowing or fanfare, and Rapunzel being killed by the Giantess who barely knew that she was there.
Are the character deaths supposed to be symbolic of something or to provide an allegory for the audience, or are they merely incidental events in a wider story where "anyone can die"?

@Valorum OK, if anyone wants to use that as a source then it should be OK.

Not sourced or complete enough for an answer, but my guess is that it's part of what I see as one of the main themes: that real life isn't like fairy tales.  In fairy tales, both good and evil get rewarded appropriately, and the story gets wrapped up neatly; in particular, good characters all survive, while evil characters die.  But the musical subverts all that: storylines don't all evolve in a satisfying or predictable way, tragedy can strike at random, and characters sometimes suffer or die unexpectedly and/or undeservedly.…

(But there's always hope, some struggles are ultimately successful, and kindness and compassion can help people face life after tragedy.)
